# Ethernet connection wireless bridge

Tags: ethernet, wireless, internet, network

I am a member of Stackoverflow, and new to Stackexchange, I have a question to which I couldn't yet find an answer to.
I'm wondering if there exists such a device as some sort of a wireless bridge to transform ethernet connection into some sort of a wireless connection. I must be clear I am not looking for some king of a modem or router.. I'm thing of a device that has at least two pieces, one, let's call it A, will connect to an ethernet wire which is connected to the ethernet port on the wall, and the second, let's call it B, would be a dongle to receive waves emitted by A. And only the B dongle will receive those waves, think of it as a bluetooth or wifi dongle but only connected to A. This device should act as if I had a very long ethernet cable that I don't have to drag arount.
I will join a sketch I did to illustrate the situation.

Thank you everyone.
[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is an access point / wireless access point / WAP - it (usually) bridges 802.3 to 802.11 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Standard access point will do this. To make only one device communicate you put an SSID (wifi network name) and passwords in the encryption that only this computer is programmed with. Please be aware of any other wifi in the area as to not interfere by putting your device on the same channel.